# Flutter QuerySnapshot return null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What I really want to do is take all the ORDER IDs ("order_id") that are in the "deliver" collection and use these IDs in another call, that is, enter in "orders" collection and inform all IDs I got in the "deliver" collection as documents.

my stream:

```
    function() {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection("delivers")
            .document("fvRpb1xDOKejJ5AEqXEeThaqhci1")
            .collection("orders")
            .snapshots()
            .listen((orders) {
          orders.documents.forEach((f) {
            print("+++++ First +++++ ${f.data}");
            Firestore.instance
                .collection("orders")
                .document(f.documentID)
                .snapshots();
          });
        });
      }

    My StreamBuilder Bellow:



body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: function(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              print("SNAPSHOT DATA ++++++ ${snapshot.toString()} ++++++}");
              // if (snapshot.hasError)
              //   print("ERRO EM ++++++ ${snapshot.error.toString()} ++++++}");
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Center(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: function, child: Text("press")));
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return circularProgress();
                  break;
                default:
                  print(
                      "CONNECTION DEFAULT ++++++ ${snapshot.toString()} ++++++}");
                  return ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data.documents
                          .map((DocumentSnapshot myOrder) {
                    return Text(myOrder["quantity"]);
                  }).toList());
              }
            }),
      ),
```

RETURNS:

I/flutter (  600): +++++ First +++++ {order_id: 2tC5gbAYLoj375w9HrKc}

Performing hot reload...                                               ⡿I/flutter (  600): SNAPSHOT DATA ++++++ AsyncSnapshot(ConnectionState.none, null, null) ++++++}

my firestore screen shots
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ZeXog80wvnR-6cTG2VCE0jOVfrSEyDaM

Comment: add ur firestore to the question

Comment: my firestore ?? the function above? I am newbe :)

Comment: i meant a screenshot of ur firestore

Comment: I added to the google drive bellow, Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `function()`.

Add return keyword before snapshots as :

```
return Firestore.instance
    .collection("delivers")
    .document("fvRpb1xDOKejJ5AEqXEeThaqhci1")
    .collection("orders")
    .snapshots();
```

or simply put the snapshot in front of the stream, as :

```
stream:Firestore.instance.collection('delivers').document('fvRpb1xDOKejJ5AEqXEeThaqhci1')____________.snapshots(),
```

Comment: thanks bro, but still return SNAPSHOT DATA ++++++ AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>(ConnectionState.none, null, null) ++++++}

Comment: Please update your latest code. For starters, remove where clauses for the simplicity. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542771/stream-builder-from-firestore-to-flutter) if it helps.

Comment: unfortunatly, the link doesn't help. I have updated the code, Sukhi

Comment: Oh! You are still not returning the snapshots.

Comment: it possible to Query as I do in flutter to streamBuilder? please read the question description above.

Comment: It is possible. Check on Firestore cross collection query. But even for that, you need to return the data. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I share a possible cause of problem of: "ALWAYS having null on snapshots results even the data is there in Firebase"

It might be your `cloud_firestore` version in `pubspec.yaml` caused the problem. I tried different methods of fetching data on Youtube, but none of them worked, I finally changed the version of `cloud_firestore` from `^0.14.4` to `^0.13.5`, and the data suddenly all appeared! Here is my specific version changes in `pubspec.yaml`: the commented are the new version that does not work.

```
  # cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  firebase: ^7.3.3
  # firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.4
  # firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4
```

This might not be the cause of your problem, but it may help some others :D

Comment: how can I set this question as answered??