# How to wait till functions complete in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have two functions named getAllContacts() which will get all the contacts from mobile and upDateAllContacts() which creates widgets using contact numbers and append it to list named registerdUsers = [] and used the registedUser widget in column.
The problem is widgets are no visible unless i navigate to another screen and come back.

```
List registeredUsers =  <Widget>[];
class  ...{
   ...
     @override
     initState() {
     getAllContacts() //It greps all the contacts from mobile
     upDateAllContacts()//contacts to create widgets which goes in to registeredUsers list
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
     column { 
       children :registeredUsers,
     }

   ...
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you function `getAllContacts` return a [Future](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future-class.html) and use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to render widgets. Whenever that future's state changes or an error occurs, FutureBuilder will call it's [`build`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder/builder.html) callback that returns appropriate widgets.

The code will look something like this:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    // Assuming loadAllContacts returns Future<Contacts>
    future: loadAllContacts(),

    // This callback will be called whenever future's state changes
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Contacts> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView(…);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Failed to load the contacts');
        } else {
            return Text('Loading the contacts');
        }
    },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `getAllContacts` a streamed event and then use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) -> this will always have the latest updates to your contacts so you won't need to explicitly update them (no more `upDateAllContacts`).

You just need to ensure that your database query/grep returns a streamed event.

For example, Firebase allows easy realtime updates. Using Firebase realtime database a stream is returned as:

> `FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('$refName').onValue`

There are quite a few threads about using stream builder - here is one for [Firebase using Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542771/stream-builder-from-firestore-to-flutter)

If the issue then becomes about where you get your data from and how to make it a stream, then [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011713/use-a-local-list-to-stream-a-streambuilder-in-flutter) asks a similar question and has no answers yet, haha.