# Fetch data from firestore and use it to make future builder to make cards?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is the database class. I'm trying to fetch data from `fetchprojects` function into a future builder but not able to do it.

```
List<Project> fetchProjects(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((e) {
        return Project(
            id: e.data['id'],
            title: e.data['title'],
            description: e.data['description'],
            prequisites: e.data['prequisites'],
            complexity: e.data['complexity'],
            affordability: e.data['affordability'],
            duration: e.data['duration'],
            members: e.data['members'],
            contact: e.data['contact']);
        }).toList();
    }
    // get brews stream
    //
    Stream<List<Project>> get projects {
        return projectCollection.snapshots().map(fetchProjects);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answers might help you how to fetch and display data from firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542771/stream-builder-from-firestore-to-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! This snippet worked for me.You can create cards by returning a listviewBuilder instead of center.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return StreamBuilder(

  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('projects').snapshots(),
   builder: (context,snapshot){


     if(!snapshot.hasData)
     return Text('data is loading');
     return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['title']),);
   }
);}
```