# Read single document field from Firestore (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document saved on Firestore, this document has a field "body" with some text inside of type "String".

It is within a collection called "messages", its path is : "chats/chatId/messages".

So my goal is to read this collection "messages" then get the latest element in it and read its field "body" printing that value on terminal.

My problem is that I read nothing.

This is the code :

```
Future<String> readMessageFromChat(String chatId, int limit) async {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> collectionToRead = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(chatId)
        .collection("messages")
        .limit(limit)
        .snapshots();
    String ret = "I have read the message : ";
    collectionToRead.forEach((element) {
      ret += element.docs.last.data()["body"].toString();
    });
    return ret;
  }
```

And this is the output :

```
flutter: id (changes randomly)
flutter: I have read the message :
```

No message is read, as you can see.

I will write also the function used to write the message before reading it :

```
Future<void> sendMessage(String id) async {
    DocumentReference documentToSave = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(id)
        .collection("messages")
        .doc("bucket");
    HashMap<String, Object> newMessage = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    newMessage.putIfAbsent("body", () => "Hi,I'm a message");
    await documentToSave.set(newMessage);
  }
```

Hope this is enough.

EDIT : Solved this is the solution :

```
Future<String> readMessageFromChat(String chatId, int limit) async {
    QuerySnapshot collectionToRead = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(chatId)
        .collection("messages")
        .limit(limit)
        .get();
    String ret = "I have read the message : ";
    collectionToRead.docs.forEach((element) {
      ret += element.data()["body"].toString();
    });
    return ret;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is mixing `streams` and `futures`. Calling `snapshots` on your query returns a `stream<QuerySnapshot>`. Your `readMessageFromChat` expects to return a `Future` however. Calling `forEach` on a stream doesn't do anything on the stream **until** the stream has fired -- which will be after the execution of your function. So you'll end up returning `I have read the message :`.

Your two options are to make it an awaited `get()` instead of a `snapshots()` or to return a `Stream<String>` and modify the string as how you were doing but with a `map` instead of a `forEach`.

Let me know what you further intend and I'll possibly update my answer.

Also, if you want the latest one, you'll need an orderBy query modifier.

### Edit

Streams can get complicated but for firestore, you're usually only ever reading from them. Streams are different from Futures as streams are continuous data. That means, at any time, a stream can give you more data. Streams are therefore `listenable`. You need to setup a listener to be notified of when more data is given to you. Usually you'd have to set stuff up yourself in the widget's init state by saying `addListener` and then dispose of it yourself and keep track of loading and error states yourself etc. However, instead of that you can just use a `StreamBuilder` that internally does all of this for you. Here is an [example from a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553853/8213910) of how to do that.

A `QuerySnapshot` means roughly what you think it means. It's just the data you get from asking executing a query, similar to any other database (`select * from customers where ...`). QuerySnapshot also holds metadata and docs as well as docChanges which can be useful.

Comment: Hi! Thanks it helped I'm almost new in Firestore and Flutter so I still have some confusion about "QuerySnapshot" , streams...Thanks for these explanations I would like to better understand how read and write data works, streams...Usually I look at FlutterFire doc but is seems old and out of date :S. For example I studied a few hours ago how Collections works in Dart, how to read key, get values...

Comment: Yeah the docs can be a little behind sometimes. I updated my answer with a bit more information but not sure it will be helpful. Happy learning !