# firebase firestore cannot read by streambuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

i am trying to fetch the data from my firestore collections, that my collection name is messages.
but when it running, streambuilder give null value from firebasefirestore stream collection.

firestore stream :

```
Stream<List<MessageMdl>>? getMyMessage({int? myId}) {
    try {
      _firestore
          .collection('messages')
          .where('user_one', isEqualTo: myId)
          .snapshots()
          .map((event) {
        var result = event.docs.map<MessageMdl>((e) {
          return MessageMdl.fromJson(e.data());
        }).toList();
         result.sort((MessageMdl a, MessageMdl b) =>
             a.createdAt!.compareTo(b.createdAt!));
        return result;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return throw Exception('failed');
    }
  }
```

streambuilder :

```
StreamBuilder<List<MessageMdl>>(
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong'));
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: Text("Loading"));
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: snapshot.data!.map((e) {
                      return Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: e.userOne == myId ? 20 : 0,
                              top: 10,
                              left: e.userOne == myId ? 0 : 20,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                maxWidth:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .7),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: e.userOne == myId
                                    ? Colors.grey.shade200
                                    : Colors.green,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12))),
                            child: Text(e.message!),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(child: Text('no data'));
              }
            },
            stream: MessageServices().getMyMessage(myId: myId),
          )
```

and here is what is `snapshot.data` value when it get printed in streambuilder :
[image]

Comment: Can you print result before returning it in getMyMessage service? By the way, you are sorting your result but you don't equal it to result again.

Comment: it give value, message one, when i call it use 
        print(_result[0].message);

Comment: when i check in connection state,  it give value to else state. not waiting state, error state, or done state. but it goes to else state and give the else return value

Comment: Did you check here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542771/stream-builder-from-firestore-to-flutter