# Flutter, The element type 'List<ListTile>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I tried geting data from firebase and display it using streamBuilder but I get this error, how do I solve it.

```
          body: 
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: firestore.collection('paymnet data').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView(
                 children: [
                   snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                     Map<String,dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                     return ListTile(
                       title: Text(data['amount']),
                       subtitle: Text(data['paid date']),
                     );
                   }).toList();
                 ],
                );
              })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `[]` from listView children

```
 body: 
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: firestore.collection('paymnet data').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.hasData?ListView(
                 children:
                   snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                     Map<String,dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                     return ListTile(
                       title: Text(data['amount']),
                       subtitle: Text(data['paid date']),
                     );
                   }).toList();
                 
                ):Container();// or add circular progress bar
              })
```

Comment: It worked but I get this during runtime on ```snapshot.data!.docs```. error: Null check operator is used on a null value. But it's not a null value cloud firestore has data.

Comment: you need to null when data is empty and follow this answer for firebase data fetching [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542771/stream-builder-from-firestore-to-flutter) and update my answer too